# Looping with Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I am new to programming. You can see the obvious redundancy in my code below. How can I write this with loops? Basically just need to count to 8 and + it to the variable names. Can't really get the hand of loops that well.

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
 $scope.funding = { startingEstimate: <?=$dataitem['incomeone'];?> };
 $scope.funding2 = { startingEstimate: <?=$dataitem['incometwo'];?> };
 $scope.funding3 = { startingEstimate: <?=$dataitem['incomethree'];?> };
 $scope.funding4 = { startingEstimate: <?=$dataitem['incomefour'];?> };
 $scope.funding5 = { startingEstimate: <?=$dataitem['incomefive'];?> };
 $scope.funding6 = { startingEstimate: <?=$dataitem['incomesix'];?> };
 $scope.funding7 = { startingEstimate: <?=$dataitem['incomeseven'];?> };
 $scope.funding8 = { startingEstimate: <?=$dataitem['incomeeight'];?> };
     computeNeeded = function() {
$scope.funding.total = 
($scope.funding.startingEstimate|0) + 
($scope.funding2.startingEstimate|0) +
($scope.funding3.startingEstimate|0) + 
($scope.funding4.startingEstimate|0) +
($scope.funding5.startingEstimate|0) + 
($scope.funding6.startingEstimate|0) +
($scope.funding7.startingEstimate|0) + 
($scope.funding8.startingEstimate|0);
};
$scope.$watch('funding.startingEstimate', computeNeeded);
$scope.$watch('funding2.startingEstimate', computeNeeded);
$scope.$watch('funding3.startingEstimate', computeNeeded);
$scope.$watch('funding4.startingEstimate', computeNeeded);
$scope.$watch('funding5.startingEstimate', computeNeeded);
$scope.$watch('funding6.startingEstimate', computeNeeded);
$scope.$watch('funding7.startingEstimate', computeNeeded);
$scope.$watch('funding8.startingEstimate', computeNeeded);
    }
```

Comment: Hint: `$scope['funding']`. But you better use arrays

Comment: Please use arrays, not sequentially named individual properties.  JS code is so much cleaner and amenable to loops when using arrays.

Comment: Maybe someone could give me a little demo?

Answer (score 0):

Start with your PHP and the `$dataitem` object. It seems as though that should just be an array where you let indexing take care of numbering instead of `incomeone`, `incometwo` etc keys. Then you can simply use PHP's [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function to serialize them into something your JavaScript can use. So at the top of your JavaScript do something like:

```
$scope.funding.startingEstimates = <?=json_encode($dataitem);?>;
```

...which will give you something like:

```
["100", "200", "300"]
```

Now you have something that's easy to iterate through, but in your case, all you're doing is summing the values. You can do that with [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead of looping:

```
computeNeeded = function(){
  $scope.funding.total = $scope.funding.startingEstimates.reduce(
    function(a, b){
      return a + b;
    }
  );
}
```

Your `$scope.$watch` function can be looped as such:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.funding.startingEstimates.length; i++){
  $scope.$watch($scope.funding.startingEstimates[i], computeNeeded);
}
```

Now anything you change in your original PHP `$dataitem` array will be picked up by the JavaScript without any extra modification. As you have it now, anything you change in the PHP requires three changes in the JavaScript.

Comment: This looks good. I am trying to implement it. This is an annoying problem...the json I get begins and ends with {[  ]} ..so I am trying to do this monsterous looking thing.. $scope.funding.testing = {<?=str_replace(array("[{","","}]",""),json_encode($query));?>};  I keep getting an error "funding not defined". Without the str_replace, I can see the data in the console but I get a syntax error.

Comment: You would get `funding not defined` when you have `$scope` defined, but not `funding` yet. So you'd have to do `$scope.funding = {};` and then do `$scope.funding.testing = <?=json_encode($query)?>`.